# Programming new PICs with PICStart+ from MPLAB 8

Tags: pic, mplab

I have an [old PICStart+ clone](https://www.olimex.com/Products/PIC/Programmers/PIC-MCP-USB/) that only works with **MPLAB 8**, it does not work with **MPLAB X**

**MPLAB 8** is no longer supported for **new PICs**.

In MPLAB you have to set the (very important) configuration bits before you program the chip.
Since MPLAB 8 doesn't know about the new PICs it probably won't be able to set the configuration bits and know the program memory size, etc of a new PIC?

Is there some simple way I can copy chip definition files from MPLAB X to MPLAB 8 to be able to program a new chip with MPLAB 8?

Are the configuration bits stored inside the hex file?
Is it possible that I could write the program and set the configuration bits in MPLAB X, then compile to hex. Then open that hex file in MPLAB 8 and write it to the chip?

I just want to be able to program a bootloader onto the chip. Then I can update my code without MPLAB or ICSP.

---

Alternatively, if the above will not work. Can you recommend a low cost ICSP programmer that supports all the new PICs? I don't care if it's Microchip, clone, or custom. I'd prefer an open source solution that's not going to be dropped the way Microchip drops their own programmers from time to time.

Comment: Just get a **genuine** PICKit3 from Microchip - it saves a load of hassle. Not sure if it's still on, but Microchip recently had a 50% sale of PICKit3's. Clones are just as likely to fall behind in support as Microchip.

Answer (score 1):

I find the Pickit3 to be the cheapest and easiest solution to your problem, some argue that it is worse than the Pikit2 however it is the latest release in low cost ICSPs from Microchip and will probably be supported for a long period of time.